# Access variable from another gradle task

Tags: gradle, groovy, build.gradle, gradlew, gradle-kotlin-dsl

I have 2 task , I want to access variable from dependent task, But its giving null value

```
task test1(type: Exec) {
    doFirst {
      def serviceUrl = "dummyUrl"
      rootProject.ext["serviceUrl"] = serviceUrl
    }
    commandLine "echo", "test1"
}

task test2(type: Exec) {
    dependsOn("test1")
    def serviceUrl = ""
    doFirst {
      serviceUrl = rootProject.findProperty("serviceUrl")
      println("serviceUrl isssss $serviceUrl")
    }
    commandLine "echo","ur ----${serviceUrl}"
}
```

commandLine "echo","ur ----${serviceUrl}" here service url is empty ,
Inside doFirst I am able to print the value , but its getting empty in commandLine, this commandLine task needs to be executed at last once I get serviceUrl value.

I tried to place commandLine in doLast block but it was giving exec==null value,
Also tried adding some dummy commandLine statement , and keeping the commandLine "echo","ur ----${serviceUrl}" in doLast block , but that commandLine is not at all executed.

Comment: You should really avoid doing this sort of thing.  In the above example, the `test1` task is doing 2 things. It's running a command __and__ it's (as a side-effect) trying to modify the global state. I assume `serviceUrl` will be the result of whatever `test1` is doing?  (as otherwise, you may as well just set `serviceUrl` in `gradle.properties`) In that case, you should write the output of `test1` on it's own to a new file in a new folder inside the build directory.  This can be the output of the task, and then `test2` can consume this output as an input.  Do you have a better example?